# Two separate text boxes with same "id" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a text boxes with same name and id, i want to get value of a particular text box and validate, can some one help how to achieve this as i am new to this.

text box name, id are same but values are different.

Comment: There should not be two elements with same `id` in a document, it should always be unique. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: You can give `class` to your `textbox` rather than `id`'s

Comment: I think in XHTML we can have this scenario, any idea about this?

Comment: No. You can't. If you want to identify them as the same like in this case, use a `class`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson rather you *shouldn't*

Comment: @Dom Would you rather someone know it's possible, and write code that takes advantage of that flaw? Or would you rather them think it's _not_ possible, and write conformant code? It's like teaching a C programer classes then they complain on why C doesn't have classes.

Comment: @ColeJohnson I agree entirely, however, it ***is*** possible: http://jsfiddle.net/kT2nE/

Comment: @Dom I know it is. I just don't want to encourage the OP and future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type=text  id='test' value="1">
<input type=text  id='test' value="2">

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value  //1
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value  //2
```

very dirty way of doing things

Comment: I am getting it like this : 

<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"5134.0800">, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"0.0000">​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"16.8000">​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"0.0000">​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"15.0000">​, 
<input type=​"text" name=​"tproj" id=​"txtboxAdjustment" value=​"5.0000">​,

and i have to get 1 particular textbox value

Comment: which one? how do you tell them apart.. you should have unique IDs

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out you shouldn't have two elements with the same identifier.

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="1">
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" value="2">
```

However, if you wanted to selected something by its value (generally a bad idea), you could so so with:

```
$(':input[value="2"]')
```

A better approach would be to have two unique text boxes like so:

```
<input type="text" id="test1" name="test" value="1">
<input type="text" id="test2" name="test" value="2">
```

Answer (score 3):

There should not be multiple elements with same Id. You can assign same class to both element and then access it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0]  //1
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[1] //2
```

Answer (score 3):

Not that you ever should have two or more of the same id's, but if you do, here's how to deal with it:

jQuery:

```
var inputs  =  $('input#my_id')
  , val1    =  inputs.eq(0).val()
  , val2    =  inputs.eq(1).val()
  ;
```

Plain JavaScript

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var input, val1, val2;
foreach ( var i in inputs )
{
    // This code may not work, but you get the idea
    input = inputs[i];
    if (input.id == 'test')
    {
        if ( !val1 ) val1 = input.value;
        else if ( !val2 ) val2 = input.value;
        else break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").val();
```

it selects only the first element with the given ID.
you could further refine your selection by specifying the tag

```
<input type=text class='fo' id='test' value="1">
<input type=text class='fp' id='test' value="2">

$("[id=test][class=fp]").val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/KY9Tu/

Answer (score 0):

same name is enough to do the trick!

```
alert($("input[name='txtboxName']").eq(0).val());
alert($("input[name='txtboxName']").eq(1).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I gave text boxes different name using 
 id="{concat('txtboxAdjustment', position())}" inside loop and it was done but i got good idea about the topic reading all the comments so thanks again.